# How to get relationship data with spring boot rest api?

Tags: json, spring, spring-boot, rest, relationship

I'm building a REST API with Spring Boot to retrieve boat information. I'm using **Spring Data Rest** and Spring Data JPA. When I get the data from the API, I don't know why the relationship data are not with the others informations.

Do I have to configure something in Spring to get the relationship with my data ?

Here is my file.

Boat entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="boat")
@Data
public class Boat {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name = "type_id", nullable = false)
    @JsonBackReference
    private BoatType type;

}
```

Boat type entity :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "boat_type")
@Data
public class BoatType {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "type")
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Set<Boat> boats;

}
```

Boat repository :

```
@CrossOrigin("http://localhost:4200")
public interface BoatRepository extends JpaRepository<Boat, Long> {
}
```

JSON response :

```
{
"_embedded": {
  "boats": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Boat 1",
      "description": "A brief description of the boat 1",
      "_links": {
        "self": {
          "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/boats/1"
        },
        "boat": {
          "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/boats/1"
        },
        "type": {
          "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/boats/1/type"
        }
      }
    },
    ...
  ]
```

}

Result expected **(with the type object too)** :

```
{
"_embedded": {
  "boats": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Boat 1",
      "description": "A brief description of the boat 1",
      "type": {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Motorboats"
      },
      "_links": {
        "self": {
          "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/boats/1"
        },
        "boat": {
          "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/boats/1"
        },
        "type": {
          "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/boats/1/type"
        }
      }
    },
    ...
  ]
```

}

I think that the problem is related with Spring Data Rest because when i do the same app with my own controller and repository, i get the data I need.

Is there a way to "configure" spring data rest?

Comment: Try to remove @JsonBackreferences and use eger loading

Comment: It doesn't change the result

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you've used `@JsonBackReference` and `@JsonManagedReference` the other way around, than you needed. You've put `@JsonBackReference` on the `type` field in your `Boat` class, whereas [its documentation](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonBackReference.html) states:

> [...] Linkage is handled such that the property annotated with this annotation **is not serialized**

So it seems like you need to put `@JsonManagedReference` annotation on it instead (see: [JsonManagedReference documentation](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonManagedReference.html)) and put `@JsonBackReference` on `boats` in your `BoatType` class.

Alternatively, you could consider using `@JsonIdentityInfo` instead. See: [the documentation](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIdentityInfo.html).

Also, [this article](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion) might be helpful. It explains various ways to handle bidirectional relationships using Jackson.

Comment: Thanks for your exlpaination. I read the related article and try quite all solution and nothing change unfortunatly...

Answer (score 0):

Change `@JsonManagedReference` and `@JsonBackReference` to `@JsonIgnoreProperties`.

In your case:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "type")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"type"})
private Set<Boat> boats;
```

and

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
@JoinColumn(name = "type_id", nullable = false)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"boats"})
private BoatType type;
```

You will avoid the infinity loop in json result and get all reference objects (relationships).

Comment: No success with this solution :(

Comment: But i try to make an uni directionnal relationship and the problem remain. So maybe it comes from an other part of my api. I remove the boat set in boat_type and no result

Comment: @JeromeSchneider Do you have all setters and getters for fields?

Comment: I use the Lombok library that do the job for me. Do you think it's related with my problem ?

Comment: Try to make manually  setters and getters. And then we can 
rule out the one problem.

Comment: Don't forget delete `@Data` annotation.

Comment: I did it yesterday and the problem remain.
I had an emptry constuctor, getters and setters and a toString method.

Answer (score 0):

The `Boat` response includes a uri to your `BoatType` resource by default since you defined a rest repository for your `BoatType` resource ([docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#projections-excerpts))

To override this behaviour, define a projection to expose the boat type data ([docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#projections-excerpts.projections.hidden-data)):

```
@Projection(name = "boatDetail", types = { Boat.class }) 
interface BoatDetail { 

  // ... all other fields you want included in the response

  BoatType getType(); 

}
```

Then include the projection as a query parameter:

**`{apiUrl}boats/1?projection=boatDetail`**

The response should now include the boat type data:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Boat 1",
    "description": "A brief description of the boat 1",
    "type": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Motorboats"
    },
    "_links": {
        // ...
    }
}
```

To automatically include the projection on a collection of resources, use an excerpt ([docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#projections-excerpts.excerpts)):

```
@RepositoryRestResource(excerptProjection = BoatDetail.class)
interface BoatRepository extends JpaRepository<Boat, Long> {}
```

Then the http response:

```
{
    "_embedded":{
        "boats":[
            {
                "id":1,
                "name":"Boat 1",
                "description":"A brief description of the boat 1",
                "type":{
                    "id":1,
                    "name":"Motorboats"
                },
                "_links":{
                    //...
                }
            },
            // ...
        ]
    }
}
```